# mat-error not shown in angular material field

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to show error in form. I'm using the angular material input :

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="phone-num">
    <input [placeholder]="'PROFILE.MOBILE_NUMBER' | translate" class="pointer" type="text" matInput
        [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber" (keyup)="onPhoneNumberChange()" [readonly]="isReadOnly" id="phoneNumberInput">

    <mat-error *ngIf="f.mobileNumber.hasError('validCountryPhone')"
        [translate]="'SHARED_VALIDATE.NOT_VALID_PHONENUMBER'"
        [translateParams]="{ value: 'PROFILE.MOBILE_NUMBER' | translate }">
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

when input is not valid, it's not showing error, but when I change `mat-error` to `div` it shows that error .

**whats the problem ?how can i solve this problem /???**

Comment: that's strange everything looks good. May be you need a formControl in your input tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found this [article](https://itnext.io/materror-cross-field-validators-in-angular-material-7-97053b2ed0cf) explaining that:

> We can learn from this that only when the form-field (the control)
> says it has errors, it displays the mat-error using a transclusion.

So we can suppose that mat-error need a formControl to check if formField has error.
in your code you will need to add in the input :

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="phone-num">
    <input [placeholder]="'PROFILE.MOBILE_NUMBER' | translate" class="pointer" type="text" matInput
        [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber" (keyup)="onPhoneNumberChange()" [readonly]="isReadOnly" id="phoneNumberInput" [formControlName]="mobileNumber"> 

    <mat-error *ngIf="f.mobileNumber.hasError('validCountryPhone')"
        [translate]="'SHARED_VALIDATE.NOT_VALID_PHONENUMBER'"
        [translateParams]="{ value: 'PROFILE.MOBILE_NUMBER' | translate }">
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

supposing your formControl's name is `mobileNumber`.

Comment: You may need to add `errorStateMatcher` to get it to work

Comment: @HDJEMAI you're right if you want to show the error message as soon as the invalid control is dirty. Or may be you can add in the ngIf `f.mobileNumber.dirty && f.mobileNumber.hasError('validCountryPhone')`?